# microsoft odbc driver manager the specified dsn contains an architecture miss match between driver and application

Tags: oracle, odbc, informatica

I'm new to informatica, I have installed informatica 9.5.1 htfix2 on my lappy with 
config: Win 7 64 bit os, Oracle 11g,Informatica 9.5.1 htfix2.

After all successfull configurations when i started workflow manager to import tables from Oracle DB i have faced below error "[microsoft odbc driver manager] the specified dsn contains an architecture mismatch between driver and application"

[image: error image]

can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I bet you are using the 64 bit ODBC driver. Remove the DSN from 64 bit and add it in the 32-bit (odbcad32.exe).
[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/702f0d9b-6cb9-49cf-9953-80d059711e60/the-specified-dsn-contains-an-architecture-mismatch-between-the-driver-and-application?forum=sqlgetstarted)

Comment: how can i remove 64 bit driver?? would u suggest me. doesn't it impact my OS?

Comment: You wouldn't remove the 64-bit driver just the DSN inside of it. How did you add the DSN in the odbcad to begin with? Go there and remove it. After doing that search (or you may have to download it) for odbcad32.exe and add the DSN there.

Comment: I have removed DSN what i have created earlier. i found odbcad32.exe shall i add again the oracle 11g DSN??

Comment: I did what u said but still issue exist same error.

Comment: Please reference the source I gave in my answer and verify that your settings match those. Also check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712362%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: For prosperity sake... what was the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution after working for seven to eight hours. I feel dumb at its simplicity :p.

- Go to *Control Panel > Administrative Tools*
- Open *ODBC Data Sources (32-bit)*. In *Users DSN* add *Data Direct 6.1 Oracle Wire Protocol*.
- Enter the respective details. E.g. if you are installing on your own system:

  - Host: `localhost`
  - Port: `1521`
  - Service: `XE` (For Oracle or dependent on database)
- Click OK and you are good to access tables on 64 bit Oracle through Informatica designer (32 Bit).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the DSN
I uninstalled Oracle client and reinstalled it clean and perfect.
Recreated the DSN and tested it.
It started working.